# SQL LIKE Operator just work when using %

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I write this query in SQL :

```
select * from words where  v like 'win'
```

SQL returns null. But when I try this one:

```
select * from words where  v like '%win'
```

or this one

```
select * from words where  v like '%win%'
```

It works and returns all words including win. I have 'win' in my cells why for first query It returns null value!?
I used rtrim(v) for omitting space but It did not work.

Comment: By 'returns null' do you mean an empty set?

Comment: In the cell is not the same as the cell.   Like without a wildcard is just an =.

Comment: Try like 'win%  this will return all words which BEGIN with win.   I suspect you have control characters in your data.

Comment: @user2182349 yes empty set

Comment: @JohnCappelletti yes maybe but how should return record which contains exact a word

Comment: Please give us an example of the exact value in `v` for a row you're expecting to be matched by `LIKE 'win'`.

Comment: Seems like a quick data-scrub is required.  Otherwise you will be chasing ghosts

Comment: @MattGibson v is a nvarchar column which i like to return record that has exactly win word  in this field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show any records with control characters

```
Select *
 From  Words
 Where CharIndex(CHAR(0),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(1),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(2),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(3),[v])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(4),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(5),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(6),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(7),[v])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(8),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(9),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(10),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(11),[v])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(12),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(13),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(14),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(15),[v])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(16),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(17),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(18),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(19),[v])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(20),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(21),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(22),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(23),[v])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(24),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(25),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(26),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(27),[v])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(28),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(29),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(30),[v])+CharIndex(CHAR(31),[v])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(127),[v]) >0
```

Since you only have /n and /t

```
Update Words set V = replace(replace(replace(v,char(10),''),char(13),''),char(9),'')
```

Comment: Yes It returned all of my records , My fields may contain `/n` or `/t` control characters at the end because I insert them from a cvs file how should I omit them?

Comment: OK, easy fix ... one moment and I will amend my answer

Comment: @mary Well done!  Data Hygiene is a constant battle.

Comment: Tnx a lot You really helped me. It worked.I was confused with it for many hours.

Comment: @mary  Happy to help.  When you get stuck, hit SO.  Lots of folks here who have "been there and done that"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there are white characters in your text.
Execute the following code on the rows with 'win' value in order to verify.

```
select cast(v as varbinary(max)) from words where ...
```

Comment: return me this error `'hex' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: So you are not using MySQL. See updated answer for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

If you're still getting empty cells then this might be an issue with SSMS "Results to Grid", change to "results to text" (CTRL-T) it might throw more light on the true nature of your source data.